# Drupal - Auto Weight

Tags: drupal, menu, drupal-7

Is there a way to automatically set a weight to nodes in Drupal? I am wanting to achieve this, because I am creating a blog layout and I want the most recent articles to appear on the top of my secondary menu rather than on the bottom.

Comment: The [weight module](https://drupal.org/project/weight) probably does what you need.

Comment: The module doesn't seem to increment in weight, it always remains at the define default weight.I am after something that dynamically increases either in the + or - in weight as new nodes are being added.

Answer (score 0):

By trying to sort by a dynamically iterating weight field, you're adding complexity to something that is really quite straight forward.  This scenario is best handled by sorting by the created, or updated date of the node.  I mean, by definition, that will allow you to sort by the most recent article.  Heck, even sorting by the node ID would be better, since you have a value that's automatically increasing for every item that's created.

A weight field should only be used when sorting needs to be empirical, like a todo list or something.  If you're using a weight field because you want to adjust the sorting of an article later on, you would still get the desired result by sorting by multiple columns (i.e. `weight ASC, created DESC`).

Comment: How would I achieve that? At the moment the nodes are being sorted in alphabetical order. How would I change it so it orders them in accordance with date created? I would like it so the most recent node appears on top

Comment: What are you using to display your nodes?